# Behavior when a Subclass doesn't invoke superclass constructor

Tags: java

According to my text book:

> If the execution of any constructor in a subclass does not invoke a
>   superclass constructor, Java automatically invokes the no-parameter
>   constructor for the superclass.

Does that mean all the superclass data field(superclass variables) would be set to null(because the constructor is a no-parameter constructor)?

Comment: ok, i got it now. thank you all! will accept answer when system allows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, if the `super`s constructor with no arguments initializes some objects - this initialization will be done.

```
class A { 
  public int x;
  A () { 
     x = 1;
  }
}
class B extends A { 
  B() { 
  }
}
```

The `B`'s constructor will still invoke `super()` as the first line (even though it is not explicitly written), and will initialize `x=1` in the process.

Comment: if the person is careless and doesn't specify them, would we get an error?

Comment: @user133466 specify what? A constructor without arguments? if one is not defined in the super class - then yes, you will get a compilation error.

Answer (score 1):

It means that superclass's fields will be set to whatever the non-parameter constructor sets them.

This may or may not be `null`. If the non-parameter superclass constructor is not defined and if the subclass's constructor doesn't set the superclass fields, then yes they will be `null`.

Comment: if the person is careless and doesn't specify them, would we get an error?

Answer (score 1):

No:

```
class A {
    public int x;
    public A() {
        x = 42;
    }
}

class B extends A {}
```

```
assert(new B().x == 42)
```

The "no-parameter constructor" does not have to be an empty constructor.

Answer (score 1):

> if the person is careless and doesn't specify them, would we get an error?

You haven't said what "them" refers to, but ...

1. If a class constructor relies (explicitly or implicitly) on a no-args constructor that its superclass does not provide (explicitly or implicitly), then that is a compilation error.
2. If the programmer accidentally leaves out the constructors in a class and its reference fields are (only) default initialized to `null` as a result, you won't get a compilation error.  (The code is valid.  The compiler cannot determine the intent of the programmer; i.e. whether the constructor was omitted accidentally or deliberately.)  But you *may* get a runtime error later on if some code uses the field / field value *assuming* it to be non-null.
3. If the programmer defines a constructor but the constructor fails to initialize some field, then the outcome is that same as 2.  No compilation error, and possible runtime error.