# SuperClass Constructor Behavior for SubClass Java

Tags: java

I'm reading java docs and reading about Constructors I got confused about the below paragraph.

> You don't have to provide any constructors for your class, but you
>   must be careful when doing this. The compiler automatically provides a
>   no-argument, default constructor for any class without constructors.
>   This default constructor will call the no-argument constructor of the
>   superclass. In this situation, the compiler will complain if the
>   superclass doesn't have a no-argument constructor so you must verify
>   that it does. If your class has no explicit superclass, then it has an
>   implicit superclass of Object, which does have a no-argument
>   constructor.

What does mean that `the compiler will complain if the superclass doesn't have a no-argument constructor`

Reference: Java Docs
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12878038/behavior-when-a-subclass-doesnt-invoke-superclass-constructor?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's imagine a Base class such as

```
public class Base {
    public Base(String s) {
    }
}
```

Let's now create a subclass:

```
public class Sub extends Base {
}
```

That won't compile, because the above code is equivalent to

```
public class Sub extends Base {
     // added by compiler because there is no explicitely defined constructor in Sub
     public Sub() {
     }
}
```

which is equivalent to

```
public class Sub extends Base {
     // added by compiler because there is no explicitely defined constructor in Sub
     public Sub() {
         // added by compiler if there is no explicit call to super()
         super();
     }
}
```

The line `super()`tries to call the no-arg constructor of Base, but there is no such constructor.

The only way to have Sub compile is thus to explicitely define a constructor such as

```
public class Sub extends Base {
    public Sub() {
        super("some string");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A constructor of the superclass and the subclass has to be called, implicitly or explicitly. Always.

If you provide a constructor for the subclass yourself, you can choose, which superclass constructor to call.

But if you don't provide a constructor for your subclass, Java creates a no-argument constructor for you. In that constructor it has to call a superclass constructor. But if there is no no-argument constructor in the superclass, Java cannot know which superclass constructor to call and which argument to use to do so.

```
class Superclass {
    Superclass(String argument) {
        //...
    }
}

class Subclass extends Superclass {
    // Implicit no-argument constructor, created by Java
    Subclass() {
        super(/* what String can Java put here? it cannot know it */);
    }
}
```

Now, if there *is* a no-argument constructor of `Superclass`, Java can just call `super();` in the default `Subclass` constructor.

Btw. that also happens automatically, if you define the `Subclass` constructor yourself and don't add an explicit call to a `Superclass` constructor. The `Subclass` constructor *always* calls a `Supeclass` constructor, be it explicitly or implicitly.

Comment: Thanks As I was Expecting.

Answer (score 1):

By default every class has a no-argument constructor. If you create class A with a constructor with arguments, when class B extends A, you need to explicitly create a constructor which will call the super class constructor with arguments. Basically when you create a constructor, you lose the default call to the no-arg constructor (unless the constructor you created is still a no-arg constructor.